# Which region is 'UI' region?

Tags: python

Can anyone help me explain what the "UI" region is? Unfortunately, I didn't get anything from their documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about Blender but 'UI' is usually an acronym for 'User Interface' if it helps.

Comment: @JohnEason It is about Blender.  Blender divides the window into [regions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html) that have names and the names are relevant to Python.  They're used, for example, in `poll` functions to decide whether Blender should run the `draw` routine of a class.

Comment: @MartyFouts Ok but the questioner wasn't exactly forthcoming about what he/she was referring to or whether they were even asking about Blender for that matter! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Indeed.  You have to both know what the Blender manual calls bits of the user interface and know that the Blender Python bpy library has an enum named something like `bl_region_type` that has a value `UI` to know what the question is actually asking.

Comment: Sometimes we have to be mindreaders in here! :^)

Comment: I knew it was about Python 'cause it was tagged "python".

Answer (score 0):

In most of Blender's Editor Types (most notably the 3D Viewport, but not in Outliner or Properties), hitting the N key makes what many people call "the N Panel" (Blender's manual calls it a Sidebar) appear/disappear in the right side of the editor.  Python calls this panel the UI region.

Please note that I'm not particularly familiar with using Python for Blender, I got this from the [Create your first Blender add-on](https://wiki.osarch.org/index.php?title=Create_your_first_Blender_add-on) article:  "We want it to appear on the N panel, which by convention is called the UI region."